# bootstrap css how to resolve conflict

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I saved and am using the bootstrap css but it conflicts with my main css.

it has tags **body, html, a, img, p**... and my css loses configuration

how can I use the bootstrap css without colliding? 
thank you

Comment: Include bootstrap.css first then include your main.css. Then your main.css will override bootstrap.

Comment: @RakeshJuyal But then there will still be collision. I think it is impossible to avoid collision unless he move his own css to classes.

Comment: I changed the order of the css before opening the question ... nothing worked

Comment: Is it specifically overriding it? Or is it just adding additional properties that throw off your design?

Comment: it replaces many properties, including my 'breadcrumb': (
I think it has no way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.over ride those styles in your css file by using !important property. bootsrtap css either override or extend your css with bootstrap css so if you want to override entire css of some class best to use !important property.

2.if your are using script in your code so its very easy to differentiate the css styles.

Answer (score 2):

Try importing your custom CSS after Bootstrap CSS.

In CSS, the “!important” suffix was originally intended to provide a method of overriding author stylesheets. Users could define their own “user stylesheets” and could use this suffix to give their rules precedence over the author’s (website creator’s) styles.
Unfortunately, and quite predictably, its usage has spread massively, but not in the right direction. Nowadays, it’s used to counteract the pain of having to deal with CSS specificity, otherwise known as the set of rules which dictate that “div h1 a” is more specific selector than “div a”. Most people that use CSS on a daily basis don’t know enough about CSS specificity to solve their problems without using the “!important” suffix.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try combining into one CSS, multiple CSS slows down the sites.
2. Even, Bootstrap has its own body,html, etc tags. You have to edit them or delete/comment them. So it avoids conflicts.
3. Generally, the last CSS property will be applied, so if you put your body, html etc at the end of Bootstrap.css, that might work, but not recommended.

Comment: I'll get the custom css and change. I think it will be easier, thanks